# Opposite for "A Semester in Review"

Tags: word-choice, titles

I've seen a few blog posts that are titled along the line of "Semester *n* in Review", where the writer analyzes his semester after experiencing it.

However, what if you analyze the upcoming semester and talk about what you know and what you expect.

What would the title be? I'm thinking something like "Semester *n* Expectations", however are there other nice-sounding titles?

Comment: "Semester Preview" seems to complement "Review"

Comment: I'd be more inclined to 'Semester forecast'.

Comment: @jejorda2 "Semester in Preview" is quite good!  It's a play on the original, and precisely conveys the intended meaning.  You should post as a formal  answer.

Answer (score 1):

I might try to find a way to use "anticipation" instead of expectation. ("In Anticipation of Semester n" is potentially more elegant, but may not be the structure you want.)

In terms of meaning, anticipation is more neutral than expectation, and conveys a more open minded state.  By contrast, expectation puts pressure on the lecturer to meet your requirements on a subject you haven't yet studied.

Anticipation also has a positive connotation, without reference to judgement, unlike expectation.